# Javascript Drag and Drop Files, then Sort

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to Sort files I pull from File Explorer by name, they sort by when they load, how would I sort them by name instead using my code below?

```
    (function() {

    // getElementById
    function $id(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }



    // output information
    function Output(msg) {
        var m = $id("messages");
        m.innerHTML = msg + m.innerHTML;
    }


    // file drag hover
    function FileDragHover(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.target.className = (e.type == "dragover" ? "hover" : "");
    }


    // file selection
    function FileSelectHandler(e) {

        // cancel event and hover styling
        FileDragHover(e);

        // fetch FileList object
        var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

        // process all File objects
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            ParseFile(f);
        }

    }


    // output file information
    function ParseFile(file) {



        // display an image
        if (file.type.indexOf("image") == 0) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                Output(
                    "<p align=center><strong>" + file.name + ":</strong><br />" +
                    '<img src="' + e.target.result + '"></p>'

                );
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        }


        // display text
        if (file.type.indexOf("text") == 0) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                Output(
                    "<p><strong>" + file.name + ":</strong></p><pre>" +
                    e.target.result.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;") +
                    "</pre>"
                );
            }
            reader.readAsText(file);
        }


    }


    // initialize
    function Init() {

        var fileselect = $id("fileselect"),
            filedrag = $id("filedrag"),
            submitbutton = $id("submitbutton");

        // file select
        fileselect.addEventListener("change", FileSelectHandler, false);

        // is XHR2 available?
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (xhr.upload) {

            // file drop
            filedrag.addEventListener("dragover", FileDragHover, false);
            filedrag.addEventListener("dragleave", FileDragHover, false);
            filedrag.addEventListener("drop", FileSelectHandler, false);
            filedrag.style.display = "block";

            // remove submit button
            submitbutton.style.display = "none";
        }

    }

    // call initialization file
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
        Init();
    }




})();
```

This code drags and drops the Files in my program and loads them, but does not sort in alphabetical, what would be the best way to sort them with my code below?

Comment: What did you try? Did you know arrays have a `sort()` function?

Comment: Problem is you have an asynchronous code in a loop.

Comment: Ok what should I do too fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   var files;

(function() {

    // getElementById
    function $id(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }


    // output information
    function Output(msg) {
        var m = $id("messages");
        m.innerHTML = msg + m.innerHTML;
    }


    // file drag hover
    function FileDragHover(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.target.className = (e.type == "dragover" ? "hover" : "");
    }


    // file selection
    function FileSelectHandler(e) {

        // cancel event and hover styling
        FileDragHover(e);

        // fetch FileList object
        var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

        // process all File objects
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            ParseFile(f);
        }

    }




    // output file information
    function ParseFile(file) {
        // display an image
        var basename = file.name.substring(0,file.name.length-4);
        files.push("<div style=\"width: 100%; overflow: hidden;\"><div style=\"width: 600px; float: left;\">" + 
                    "<strong>" + basename + ".pdf:</strong><br />" +
                    '<iframe src="\\\\sovarchpri01\\d$\\1000Sunrise\\Process\\stage\\' + basename +".pdf#view=fit" + '"height="75%" width="500px"></iframe></p>' +
                    "</div><div style=\"margin-left: 620px;\">" + 
                    "<strong>" + basename + ".png:</strong><br />" +
                    "<img src=\"\\\\sovarchpri01\\d$\\Fleissner\\ORG_5535_Documents\\" + basename + ".png\" height=\"75%\" width=\"500px\">" +
                    "</div> ");
    }

    function sortFiles() {
        files.sort().reverse();
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
            Output(files[i]);
        }
    }

    function resetWindow(){
        window.location.reload(true)
    }

    // initialize
    function Init() {

        var fileselect = $id("fileselect"),
            filedrag = $id("filedrag"),
            submitbutton = $id("submitbutton"),
            sortbutton = $id("sortbutton"),
            resetbutton = $id("resetbutton")
            resetbutton2 = $id("resetbutton2");;

        files = new Array();    
        // file select
        fileselect.addEventListener("change", FileSelectHandler, false);

        // is XHR2 available?
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (xhr.upload) {

            // file drop
            filedrag.addEventListener("dragover", FileDragHover, false);
            filedrag.addEventListener("dragleave", FileDragHover, false);
            filedrag.addEventListener("drop", FileSelectHandler, false);
            filedrag.style.display = "block";

            // remove submit button
            submitbutton.addEventListener("click", sortFiles , false); //style.display = "none";

            sortbutton.addEventListener("click", sortFiles , false);
            resetbutton.addEventListener("click", resetWindow , false);
            resetbutton2.addEventListener("click", resetWindow , false);

        }

    }

    // call initialization file
    if (window.FileReader) {
        Init();
    }


})();
```